# Why are my cabinet doors opening on their own?

Tags: cabinets

House and kitchen cabinets are 40 years old and custom built. Recently we noticed a cabinet door opening/ not staying closed, by itself. Opens about 4 inches. Next door cabinet soon started opening about 2 inches, 3rd one opens a bit. I'm worried this set of cabinets could fall.

Comment: Post a picture of the hinges.  Possible they are getting weak.

Comment: Do the hinges that remain closed have any spring effect built in? More details, please.

Comment: replace/install cabinet door magnetic catches to hold the doors closed.    https://www.homedepot.com/b/Hardware-Cabinet-Hardware-Cabinet-Latches/Magnetic/N-5yc1vZc274Z1z1750k

Comment: check (what should be obvious) with a long level the squareness and levelness of mounted cabinets, it's doors, walls, and floors.  Best case loose cabinet door hinge, worst case house foundation failing and everything is shifting.  Aside from air gust only thing that'll cause a door to open is gravity and things not being level, nothing complicated.

Comment: https://abc11.com/chatham-county-forever-home-dream-nightmare-code-violations/13321024/

Comment: Square, level *and plumb.*

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in a house stays square over time. Things need adjustment periodically to compensate for that for best operation. (Or you could just install a spring latch rather than expecting the doors to stay closed by gravity.)

Nothing you've said suggests that the cabinets are mechanically weak, just that things have shifted a small amount.